# Enable/Disable spring application modules at runtime

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, togglz

I'm finding way how to enable/disable modules at runtime. I found [togglz framework](http://www.togglz.org/) so I just want to ask if I can achieve what I want with it or with any other tool.

let's say I have following maven modules (each of them has it's own spring configuration eg `AccountQueryConfiguration`, `AccountCommandConfiguration`, ...)

`- account
--- account-query
--- account-command
--- account-rest
- user
--- user-query
--- user-command
--- user-rest`

I would like to stop some/all of account modules at runtime. Can I do this with togglz or something similar?

I think I can do this with springs [ApplicationContext](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationContext.html) and removing beans at runtime...right?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by disabling modules. If you want to enable specific beans at runtime look at the Profile and Conditional annotations.

Comment: I know about profile... but can you switch profiles at runtime (when application is running)?